# Can I unlock special characters I previously failed to find?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

My question is about the special characters you can unlock from time to time (Luke, Leila, Yoda, etc.).
If you happen to refuse to find them when prompted or the game crashes when you do (like in the previous releases in WP8), is the character lost forever? Can you be prompted to look for him again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, I refused Luke the first time and was asked to find him again later that day.